# How to pass RuntimeWarning in printing outputs?

Tags: python, compiler-errors, save, runtime

I run my code and it works properly. Because it contains random numbers, some of these numbers lead to invalid values for the functions in code (it is normal and we don't know which number leads to invalid value). But in printing Python continues printing and just shows this error one or two times for those numbers:

`RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in...`

as the following:

```
.
.
.
174.45044049634845 0.2462826944657234 0.07030551312264746 0.5748635625886386
173.507852282145 0.22849596593782928 0.02418486733987143 0.5342742271386651
172.72866355236476 0.23561628491593717 0.00276512493464073 0.5299714003809053

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\...        return (Om*(1+z)**3+omg0*(1+z)**6+(1-Om-omg0))**(-0.5)
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\...", line 364
    warnings.warn(msg, IntegrationWarning)
IntegrationWarning: The occurrence of roundoff error is detected, which prevents
  the requested tolerance from being achieved.  The error may be
  underestimated.

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\...", line 1874
    r = _umath_linalg.det(a, signature=signature)
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in det
172.72866355236476 0.23561628491593717 0.00276512493464073 0.5299714003809053
172.83987258470256 0.23561628491593717 0.00276512493464073 0.521804452272765
172.94243737214325 0.23561628491593717 0.00276512493464073 0.5142747330950714
173.81824790232395 0.2447458303542599 -0.014745034802849322 0.3863934727161802
173.81824790232395 0.2447458303542599 -0.014745034802849322 0.3863934727161802
175.04959056025322 0.2447458303542599 -0.014745034802849322 0.2964727561196514
.
.
.
```

Python continue to print but I can not save them in a file, I have to copy and paste. It cannot possible if we have 5,000,000 data.

Is there any way to write these outputs in a file?

Answer (score 0):

Handle the exception yourself by wrapping the offending line in a try block:

```
try:
    r = _umath_linalg.det(a, signature=signature)
except RuntimeError as ex:
    error_file.write(ex)
```

Comment: I have `hhh=np.linalg.det(zz)*0.000001` in my code. where should I write this code you said

Comment: Put the `try:` above that line, and the `except` below it.

Comment: I asked it because `hhh=np.linalg.det(zz)*0.000001` is in a function. I mean, `def function(....),   ......, hhh=np.linalg.det(zz)*0.000001, return hhh`  I never used `try` and `except` in function.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, `warnings` and `errors` are barriers for saving data in a file, so we need them to be removed. You can disable `WarningError`s by the use of:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

at the top of your code. then, you can write outputs in a `text file`.

Also, you can use `try and except` blocks, but remember these kind of blocks are very bad for speed of program. If you expect your program to print out `10,000,000`, even with cluster pcs you need a long time.

Comment: So, this line of code does not anything to the rest of code?

Comment: Nope. lean back and use it as you wish :)